# MySQL Sleep mode Error

Tags: mysql

We are connecting our Massmail server from windows machine to our Linux machine hosting the MySQL server. We are using MySQL driver to connect the two servers. However, since this week, the query (from windows machine) brings data but the process hangs on the Windows machine.
however, when checked in MySQL using `Show Processlist`; command, it shows that the command is in SLEEP mode?

The recordset has 98K rows and it goes to sleep around 79K rows. I checked the queries and it runs in the phpMyAdmin in under a second.

Any idea?

Edit 1: the table type is MyISAM and where fields are indexed.

Edit 2: My thought is that the script that calls the Table takes the data and does some processing. In the meanwhile the process in MySQL goes to sleep but script somehow freezes and hence keeps the MySQL thread not dying. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was due to low empty space (152mb) in C drive on the windows server. Removing some files fixed the problem.

Thanks